# How to iterate over two or more JSONs objects that came from requests in a jade template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jade4j

I am facing a issue at getting results from a REST api requests that return JSON objects.

How am I getting the results in jade template?

```
if team
   each member in team[0].members
     .team-member
        h4= member.name
```

How is the data format for this object?

```
{
    "team": [
        {
            "_id": "5e22f66a77011b3350a3285f",
            "members": [
                {
                    "_id": "5e264e4897534916ad8594a1",
                    "email": "email@server.com",
                    "name": "name",
                    "role": "Project Manager",
                    "twitter": "https://twitter.com/",
                    "facebook": "https://www.facebook.com/",
                    "linkedin": "https://www.linkedin.com/in//"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is working fine, but I need more than one request. That is, there is more than one JSONs objects.

So, I have two requests to call in a same controller where each one returns a JSON object. I have implemented an approach that uses promises so that I can wait the requests to finish and after that I can store the output of each request in an array so that I can render only once.

How do I render the data?

```
       for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

            res.render('index', results[i]); // I cannot do it!

        }
```

I can't do it because I get some error regarding headers sent more than once: it returns a error of the kind => `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT`

How can I render without any error about headers?

```
        var output = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

            output.push(results[i]);
            //res.render('index', results[i]);

        }

        res.render('index', output);
```

But now I can't acess "team" neither "member" structure in JSON object.

How would I iterate over it?

== EDIT ==

After getting some answers, I think I have to share more details about the code. It is as follows:

```
   var url = ApiConfiguration.getApiURL();
    var requests = [{
            url: url + '/api/team/members/',
            headers: {'headers': 'apitoken'}},
        {
            url: url + '/api/service/',
            headers: {'headers': 'apitoken'}}
    ];

    Promise.map(requests, function (obj) {
        return request(obj).then(function (body) {
            return JSON.parse(body);
        });
    }).then(function (results) {

        var output = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

            output.push(results[i]);
            //res.render('index', results[i]);

        }

        res.render('index', output);

    }, function (err) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge responses together into one object and send it to jade:

```js
let output = {};
for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  output = { ...output, ...results[i] };
}
res.render('index', output);
```

Comment: There is another request and not just "team". Take a look. I have provided more details that I hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

‍ You can make something like this code below :

```js
var url = ApiConfiguration.getApiURL();
var requests = [{
    url: url + '/api/team/members/',
    headers: {
        'headers': 'apitoken'
    }
}, {
    url: url + '/api/service/',
    headers: {
        'headers': 'apitoken'
    }
}];

// I'm using Promise.map from 'bluebird'.
// make sure it's same
Promise.map(requests, function(obj) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // I'm using request from: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request
        // make sure you too
        request(obj, function(err, res, body) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            return resolve(JSON.parse(body));
        })
    })
}).then(function(results) {
    const members = [];
    results.map(result => {
        if (result && result.team && result.team.length > 0) {
            result.team.forEach(team => {
                members = [...members, ...team.members]
            })
        }
    });

    res.render('index', members);

}).catch(ex => {
    console.log(ex.message);
    console.log(ex);
})
```

And now, in your `.jade`, you can make something like this code below :

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title=title
    body
        h1 This page is produced by Jade engine
        p some paragraph here..
        if members
        each member in members
          .team-member
              h4= member.name
```

I hope it's can help you .

Comment: hello! I have provided more details that I hope it clarifies.

Comment: i've been update my answer, you can check it out. **Make sure your** `.jade` same with mys.

Comment: I mean in `each member in members`. If you never want to change your variable name, then make sure you change the variable name in the render method or add some variable to store team in mapping function.